# How do I change the background color of a JPanel using JRadioButton

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is that I am trying to change the background color of a JPanel using JRadioButtons but when I click on the JRadioButton the background color of the JPanel doesn't change

here is the code I have written. What is the problem with the ActionListener it doesn't seem to work here

I here used JRadioButtons and created 3 of them red,blue,green. I placed them in a ButtonGroup. after this I added an actionListener associated with it. Then I created a JPanel and added a border to it. its name is colorBox. and then in the class changeListener i created an if and else statement, stating that if e.getSource or red(Button).isSelected() then the background of the colorBox panel will be set to red, and the same for the rest of the buttons i did the same but the color of that panel didn't change after I clicked the JRadioButton. **What is the problem here? How can I correct this**

```
package aui;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class E_3_2  extends JFrame 
{   private static int FRAME_WIDTH = 500, FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
    private JRadioButton red,blue,green;
    private ButtonGroup group;
    private JPanel panel, colorBox;
    private ActionListener listener;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new E_3_2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Change the background Color of a Panel");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public E_3_2()
    {
        red = new JRadioButton("Red");
        red.addActionListener(listener);
        blue = new JRadioButton("Blue");
        red.addActionListener(listener);
        green = new JRadioButton("Green");
        green.addActionListener(listener);
        
    
        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(red);
        group.add(blue);
        group.add(green);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(blue);
        panel.add(green);
        panel.add(red);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
//      
        
        colorBox = new JPanel();
        colorBox.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Color Box"));
        colorBox.setSize(150, 150);
        add(colorBox);
        
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    }
    
    class ChangeListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            
            String clickedButton = e.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println(clickedButton + " clicked");
            if(e.getSource() == red || red.isSelected())
            {
                colorBox.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == blue || blue.isSelected())
            {
                colorBox.setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == green || green.isSelected())
            {
                colorBox.setBackground(Color.green);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned anything to `private ActionListener listener`, in order to fix this, add the line `listener = new ChangeListener();` to your constructor.

Also, the blue button does not work because you never gave it a listener.

Your constructor will now look something like this:

```java
public E_3_2()
    {
        listener = new ChangeListener();

        red = new JRadioButton("Red");
        red.addActionListener(listener);
        blue = new JRadioButton("Blue");
        blue.addActionListener(listener);
        green = new JRadioButton("Green");
        green.addActionListener(listener);

        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `listener` object is declared as an `ActionListener`.  In order to use your own listener, you need to use the `ChangeListener` that uses the overridden method.

For added efficiency, you could try using an anonymous inner class just to make it easier on yourself.  For example:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
    
    }
});
```